# butt-to-butt as an adverb

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When I entered a Persian sentence to Google Translate it returned:

> To investigate residual stresses and distortions, the geometry of this connection (flange to hemisphere) is considered butt-to-butt with full penetration welding.

It's could be a special field, but you may still consider of it has meaning or not. It seems *butt welding* is type of welding, just I'm not sure if *butt-to-butt* can be used as an adverb here or not.

It may also be said like this:

> To investigate residual stresses and distortions, the geometry of this connection (flange to hemisphere) is considered to be butt-to-butt with full penetration.

I'm afraid that but to but may not be a proper word here, I may could rewrite it as follows to use *but weld*:

> To investigate residual stresses and distortions, the geometry of this connection (flange to hemisphere) is considered to be a butt weld with full penetration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butt_welding

Comment: Are you a welder? What is the purpose of translating to English (I assume you speak Persian, so can understand the meaning of this) I'm not a welder, and the translation means nothing to me.

Comment: @Jamesk, Not I am not a welder, and unfortunately its not even my field of study, but a student asked me to translate a short piece of an article to English.

Comment: Googling **welding butt** brings up a number of images illustrating **butt welding**. Presumably the meaning, judging from the illustrations, is that the two butts involved should be placed against one another. While I have no experience of welding, I don't see a problem with either the placement or the grammar of butt to butt.